# Is there a way to use the native OS X spell checking in Firefox?

Tags: macos, firefox, spell-check

Is there a way to use the native OS X spell checking in Firefox? I think the answer is probably no, because this question was asked concerning Thunderbird on OS X, but maybe it's different with Firefox.

Comment: I was search about how firefox spell checking works. It uses built in spell checker. If there were a spell checker plug-in to override built-in checker, you might change that. Unfortunately I can't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is now way you can use Mac OS X built in spell checking, only the spell checking that is built into Firefox.